# Selenide Library to wait until new window popup

Tags: selenide

I am trying to find easier way to wait for a new window to be displayed (popup).
Is there any selenide api example where I could wait until a new window popup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use one of the following methods for SelenideElement

- [waitUntil(Condition condition, long timeoutMilliseconds)](http://selenide.org/javadoc/3.5.1/com/codeborne/selenide/SelenideElement.html#waitUntil-com.codeborne.selenide.Condition-long-)
- [waitUntil(Condition condition, long timeoutMilliseconds, long pollingIntervalMilliseconds)](http://selenide.org/javadoc/3.5.1/com/codeborne/selenide/SelenideElement.html#waitUntil-com.codeborne.selenide.Condition-long-long-)
- [waitWhile(Condition condition, long timeoutMilliseconds)](http://selenide.org/javadoc/3.5.1/com/codeborne/selenide/SelenideElement.html#waitWhile-com.codeborne.selenide.Condition-long-)
- [waitWhile(Condition condition, long timeoutMilliseconds, long pollingIntervalMilliseconds)](http://selenide.org/javadoc/3.5.1/com/codeborne/selenide/SelenideElement.html#waitWhile-com.codeborne.selenide.Condition-long-long-)

Here are [test examples](https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/blob/dba416351c98abf616eee09d1273474d5ad84c3f/src/test/java/integration/ElementDisappearsTest.java) from Selenide Github repository

```
  @Test
  public void waitUntilDisappears() {
    $("button").waitUntil(disappears, 2000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I used to do is count the windows just before a click to make sure there is just one, then click to open new window and then have a condition to wait until window count is 2, then switch to it.   There might not be a Selenide specific way to count windows, but you can with Selenium itself.  Then, you can further assert on it my checking the new window URL string to make sure.